# Algebraic Manipulation to find equilibrium points ODE

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The schaefer model for fisheries is given by:

$\frac{dy}{dt} = r (\frac{1-y}{K})y-Ey$

Where $Ey$ is the rate at which fish are caught, $r$ is the rate of growth and $K$ is the carrying capacity.

Clearly one equilibrium point of this is where $y=0$ but the other is supposedly $K(\frac{1-E}{r})$ and I can't see how.

One example of working that I found said:

$r (\frac{1-y}{K})y=0 \leftrightarrow y(\frac{K-EK}{r-y})=0$

It doesn't make any sense to me how the first term there leads to the second. Try as I might, I can not make $r (\frac{1-y}{K})y=y(\frac{K-EK}{r-y})=0$

The way I would have multiplied $r (\frac{1-y}{K})y=0$ out is to do:

$\frac{yr-ry^2}{K} - Ey=0$

$yr-ry^2-KEy=0$

$r-ry-KE=0$

$r(1-y)-KE=0$

And I can't seem to get any closer to the required solution... Can anybody tell he what I am doing wrong and how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't copied the differential equation right; it should be $1-(y/K)$, not $(1-y)/K$. (That factor should be zero when the population $y$ equals the carrying capacity $K$; cf. the logistic growth model.)

Then the equilibra are given by
$$
0 = r \left( 1- \frac{y}{K} \right) y-Ey = y \left( r \left( 1 - \frac{y}{K} \right) - E \right)
\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad
y=0 \quad\text{or}\quad r \left( 1 - \frac{y}{K} \right) - E = 0
.
$$
The second equation gives $1-y/K = E/r$, so $y/K=1-E/r$, and hence $y = K (1-E/r)$.

(So you also didn't copy the answer right; it's $1-(E/r)$, not $(1-E)/r$.)